# How do I fix '530-5.5.1 Authentication Required' error when trying to send e-mail from localhost?

Tags: php, email, smtp

I've been trying to send e-mail from the following PHP script running on my localhost, with G-mail as my SMTP relay host.

```
<?php
// The message
$message = "Line 1\r\nLine 2\r\nLine 3";

$message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");

$headers = 'From: <my-email>@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: <my-email>@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

// Send Mail
if (true==mail('<other email>@gmail.com', 'My Subject', $message, $headers, '-f<other email>@gmail.com'))
{
    echo "E-mail successfully sent.";
}
else
{
    echo "E-mail failed.";
}
?>
```

Although the mail function returns 'TRUE', no e-mail actually gets delivered, and I keep getting the following error when I look at the mail log:

Also, in looking at the `mail.log` file, the following errors were recorded:

```
Aug 17 22:00:03 unknownf81edfd84850 postfix/smtp[1714]: maps_find: smtp_sasl_passwd: smtp.gmail.com: not found
Aug 17 22:00:03 unknownf81edfd84850 postfix/smtp[1714]: maps_find: smtp_sasl_passwd: smtp.gmail.com:587: not found
Aug 17 22:00:03 unknownf81edfd84850 postfix/smtp[1714]: smtp_sasl_passwd_lookup: no auth info found (sender=`rrodriguez6@unknownf81edfd84850.att.net', host=`smtp.gmail.com')
Aug 17 22:00:03 unknownf81edfd84850 postfix/smtp[1714]: > smtp.gmail.com[173.194.219.108]:587: MAIL FROM:<rrodriguez6@unknownf81edfd84850.att.net> SIZE=389
Aug 17 22:00:03 unknownf81edfd84850 postfix/smtp[1714]: > smtp.gmail.com[173.194.219.108]:587: RCPT TO:<rlrodriguez.rivera@gmail.com>
Aug 17 22:00:03 unknownf81edfd84850 postfix/smtp[1714]: > smtp.gmail.com[173.194.219.108]:587: DATA
Aug 17 22:00:03 unknownf81edfd84850 postfix/smtp[1714]: vstream_fflush_some: fd 15 flush 108
Aug 17 22:00:03 unknownf81edfd84850 postfix/smtp[1714]: vstream_buf_get_ready: fd 15 got 133
Aug 17 22:00:03 unknownf81edfd84850 postfix/smtp[1714]: < smtp.gmail.com[173.194.219.108]:587: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at
Aug 17 22:00:03 unknownf81edfd84850 postfix/smtp[1714]: < smtp.gmail.com[173.194.219.108]:587: 530 5.5.1  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257 j2sm2579221ywj.12 - gsmtp
Aug 17 22:00:03 unknownf81edfd84850 postfix/smtp[1714]: connect to subsystem private/bounce
```

Is it possible that postfix cannot read my `sasl_passwd.db` file?

Below is the content of my `sasl_passwd` file:

```
smtp.gmail.com:587 <my gmail account>:�<my gmail password>
```

Also, I have the following settings in my `main.cf` file:

```
#Gmail SMTP
relayhost = smtp.gmail.com:587
# Enable SASL authentication in the Postfix SMTP client.
smtp_sasl_auth_enable=yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options=
# Enable Transport Layer Security (TLS), i.e. SSL.
smtp_use_tls=yes
smtp_tls_security_level=encrypt
tls_random_source=dev:/dev/urandom
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/ssl/cacert.pem
debug_peer_list=smtp.gmail.com
debug_peer_level=3
```

One thing I did notice is that when I run postmap to create the `sasl_passwd.db` file, I get the following warning:

```
postmap: warning: sasl_passwd, line 0: expected format: key whitespace value
```

Comment: Use [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). It makes things so much easier.

Comment: Thanks!  I tried using PHPMailer, and it really does work wonders.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I needed to configure my Google Apps account so that they would allow SMTP relay.  Once I did that, I was able to start sending e-mails both using the PHPMailer and the regular mail function in PHP.